# Why is 'get' necessary in this MobX example

Tags: javascript, mobx

In part of a [MobX tutorial](https://mobx.js.org/getting-started.html) one example uses the getter syntax for a property called report.

```
class ObservableTodoStore {
@observable todos = [];
@observable pendingRequests = 0;

constructor() {
    mobx.autorun(() => console.log(this.report));
}

@computed 
get completedTodosCount() {
    return this.todos.filter(
        todo => todo.completed === true
    ).length;
}

@computed 
get report() {
    if (this.todos.length === 0)
        return "<none>";
    return `Next todo: "${this.todos[0].task}". ` +
        `Progress: ${this.completedTodosCount}/${this.todos.length}`;
}

addTodo(task) {
    this.todos.push({
        task: task,
        completed: false,
        assignee: null
    });
}
}

const observableTodoStore = new ObservableTodoStore();

observableTodoStore.addTodo("read MobX tutorial");
observableTodoStore.addTodo("try MobX");
observableTodoStore.todos[0].completed = true;
observableTodoStore.todos[1].task = "try MobX in own project";
observableTodoStore.todos[0].task = "grok MobX tutorial";

// Next todo: "read MobX tutorial". Progress: 0/1
// Next todo: "read MobX tutorial". Progress: 0/2
// Next todo: "read MobX tutorial". Progress: 1/2
// Next todo: "grok MobX tutorial". Progress: 1/2
```

When I remove the get keyword from the report property,

```
@computed 
report() { 
// ...
```

and then change the call to that report to reflect that it is no longer a getter,

```
constructor() {
    mobx.autorun(() => console.log(this.report()));
}
```

then I still get a console output. However it is very different.

```
// Next todo: "grok MobX tutorial". Progress: 1/7
// Next todo: "grok MobX tutorial". Progress: 1/8
```

Why is the result so different? I thought that the decision to use getters is more of a style choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `get` in combination with the `@computed` decorator.

The documentation for the [`computed` decotator](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/computed-decorator.html) states that:

> If you have decorators enabled you can use the `@computed` decorator on
>   any getter of a class property to declaratively created computed
>   properties.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tholle. So it's a MobX thing. Would you have any idea why I still get two lines of output?

Comment: Actually, stand down on that question in my last comment. I think that the extra lines appear because the page, on which the example runs, is remembering previous runs. Cheers.